Can I change the null MINT authority of my spl-token if I am the updateAuthority?
Can I change the "null" MINT authority of my spl-token if I am the updateAuthority of the token?
Or just can update the metadata?

This is not possible.
Once you set the mint authority as null you've revoked the updateAuthority from minting more tokens.
